# Joomla H1/H2 Tags

Tags: html, joomla, html-heading

Can anyone explain to me please why the heading tag for title is H2 not H1 in Joomla 3.0?

And also does anyone know how to change this? Considering there are no H1 tags, but once you put sub headings in using H2 that is surely no good for the old SEO?

I have searched the Global Config and Google, this applies to Article Titles and Menu Titles

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Page title is H1. 
Page title can be set in any menu item or it sometimes falls back to an annoying default value like Contact.

Comment: Thats what I mean though... The page title is a H2 not H1, there are no H1, I double checked in the source code.. see my screenshot attached above

Comment: Are you using an override? 

https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/master/components/com_content/views/article/tmpl/default.php#L27   Which is 3.0

Comment: Nope, no override that I have done and just checked that file on my server it is using H1 tags, so can't be that...

Comment: https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/master/components/com_content/views/article/tmpl/default.php#L27  shows h1 there for the article layout.  Are you positive that is the page title and not the article title?

Comment: Ok, so maybe I should have realised this before, how do I swap from Article H to Page H as even when I use the menu title it uses H2 tags?

Comment: Ok, just managed it, thank you - but how can I set this as default because I am finding it a bit confusing

Comment: What is it you want to set as default?

Comment: For the article titles to be H1 page titles

Comment: I don't know how you made the change so it's hard to say, but it really sounds like you need to make a layout override with h1 in it.